# Deploy Play! 2.2.x on java based shared hosting

Tags: playframework-2.0

Currently, I'm planning to deploy my `Play! 2.2.x` app on a shared hosting service. Since it's cheaper than to deploy it on cloud like heroku.

I don't have any experience on deploying my app on java shared hosting, like tomcat and jetty. However, I do know that for tomcat and jetty, I need to convert my app into `war` file. Also, I know that `Play! 2.2.x` doesn't support `war` file deployment.

So, does that mean I couldn't deploy my app on shared hosting, like http://www.jvmhost.com/? Or even if I could, would the tomcat or jetty be useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Play2War plugin for Play 2.2.x

https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/

> ```
> Current versions:
>     Play 2.2.x          : 1.2
>     Play 2.3.0 -> 2.3.1 : 1.3-beta1 (Scala 2.10 & 2.11)
>     Play 2.3.2+         : 1.3-beta3 (Scala 2.10 & 2.11)
> ```

Comment: Yup, I heard that. If so, then what happen to the `netty`? If it still uses `netty` then should I look for shared hosting with only jvm installed? Sorry for asking silly question, because I don't have any exp. in java environment.

Comment: AFAIK, play2war doesn't use netty. It uses whatever container you put the war file in. So tomcat would be fine.

Comment: Will it decrease the performance of the app? If so, then I think I should forget about the shared hosting.

Comment: I didn't notice any difference in performance when I tried play2war, but always measure.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to deploy my app on shared hosting using Tomcat, but instead I want to use the built-in server which is Netty? If it could, then which one is the best?

Comment: I don't think that would work. You could sneakily start up a Play netty server from within a war, but it would have to listen on a different port which would probably be blocked by the firewall. I think Tomcat will be fine.